# How to increase the limit of project quantity?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

I've tried to add a Project admin to the project after creation, and got an error:

```
"code": 1006,
"message": "You have reached the maximum number of projects for BIM 360 Docs"
```

Comment: How does this happen? Are you still able to create a new project, but cannot add project admin into the project? The information you provided is limited to tell what happened. Could you share more details? Thanks!

Comment: In addition, how many projects do you have already in that hub?

Comment: I have 92 projects.
I can create project with Forge API,but i can't make it active by adding project admin.
Also, i can't create new project with BIM360 site, or add project admin to an existing inactive project.

Comment: May I ask you a favor to go to your BIM360 Account Admin (https://admin.b360.autodesk.com/admin/{PROJECT_ID}/dashboard) to check if your subscription is validated and if your total member number exceeds the total subscription number you purchased?

Comment: I have trial subscription with enabled developers account.
Also,I've tried to add myself as project admin.

I changed some project statuses from active to archive, and it works, but i still have a limit near 90 projects

Comment: Volodymyr - If you have a trial converted one, try contacting  bim360appsactivations@autodesk.com    Explain what you are trying to do and why you need so many projects for dev purpose.  related instruction:   https://fieldofviewblog.wordpress.com/2017/08/31/bim-360-docs-account-for-development/    https://fieldofviewblog.wordpress.com/2017/08/18/no-custom-integrations-tab/

Comment: Volodymyr - When you do, please also provide Account ID and your e-mail as account owner.